# Go udp connection dial once, and send many

Tags: go

please consider this code below, it is a simplified version of a service. I launch a no. of goroutines as needed during its lifetime, and as they go about doing things, they need to send udp messages to a set destination.

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "net"
        "time"
)

const (
        udp_dest = "192.168.1.200:514"
)

func main() {
        fmt.Println("Hello")
        message := "this is a test"
        log_message(&message)
        go worker(1)
        go worker(2)
        go worker(3)
        go worker(4)
        time.Sleep(3009 * time.Second)
}

func log_message(message *string) {
        RemoteAddr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", udp_dest)
        if err != nil {
                //fmt.Println("Err,  net.ResolveUDPAddr", err)
                return
        }
        conn, err := net.DialUDP("udp", nil, RemoteAddr)
        if err != nil {
                return
        }
        udp_message := fmt.Sprintf("<30> %s", *message)
        Bytes, _ := conn.Write([]byte(udp_message))
        log.Printf("Sent %d Bytes to %s\n", Bytes, udp_dest)
}

func worker(tag int) {
        i := 0
        for {
                worker_message := fmt.Sprintf("Some message from worker%d, loop: %d", tag, i)
                log_message(&worker_message)
                // do some work..
                time.Sleep(300 * time.Second)
                i += 1
        }
}
```

In my `log_message`, everytime it gets called we're calling `net.DialUDP` which I feel is wasteful. I tried experimenting with global variables `&net.UDPConn` et al, but could not get to work.

Please show how to achieve/optimize this? There's only one UDP destination, and I'd like the daemon to `Dial` once at its start, and then just `Write` as needed.

Thanks!

---

here's what I got so far:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "net"
        "time"
)

const (
        udp_dest = "192.168.1.200:514"
)

var (
        myconn *net.UDPConn
)

func main() {
        fmt.Println("Hello")
        message := "this is a test"
        log_message(&message)
        go worker(1)
        go worker(2)
        go worker(3)
        go worker(4)
        time.Sleep(3009 * time.Second)
}

func log_message(message *string) {

        if myconn == nil {

                fmt.Println("Setting up myconn!")
                RemoteAddr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", udp_dest)
                if err != nil {
                        //fmt.Println("Err,  net.ResolveUDPAddr", err)
                        return
                }
                myconn, err = net.DialUDP("udp", nil, RemoteAddr)

                if err != nil {
                        return
                }
        }

        udp_message := fmt.Sprintf("<30> %s", *message)
        Bytes, _ := myconn.Write([]byte(udp_message))
        log.Printf("Sent %d Bytes to %s\n", Bytes, udp_dest)
}

func worker(tag int) {
        i := 0
        for {
                worker_message := fmt.Sprintf("Some message from worker%d, loop: %d", tag, i)
                log_message(&worker_message)
                // do some work..
                time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
                i += 1
        }
}
```

Comment: What problem did you have using a package level variable?

Comment: thanks, could you please show me what package level variable to use here?

Comment: We are referring to the same thing when mentioned that you tried a global variable.  What problem did you encounter with that approach?  Show the code.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.  Move the setup code to a function and call it before starting the goroutines.

```
func main() {
    if err := setupLog(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Hello")
    ... same as before
}

func setupLog() error {
    fmt.Println("Setting up myconn!")
    RemoteAddr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", udp_dest)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    myconn, err = net.DialUDP("udp", nil, RemoteAddr)
    return err
}

func log_message(message *string) {
    udp_message := fmt.Sprintf("<30> %s", *message)
    Bytes, _ := myconn.Write([]byte(udp_message))
    log.Printf("Sent %d Bytes to %s\n", Bytes, udp_dest)
}
```

The code in the question does not work because there's a data race on `myconn`.